# Использование dll на C# в проекте делфи

Tags: delphi

У меня есть библиотека для работы с кассой написанная на  C#. Не является COM-объектом. Как работать с такими библиотеками в делфи?

Comment: можно сделать api

Comment: Не могли бы вы пояснить подробнее?

Comment: Если экспортируемые функции не используют в параметрах специфические для шарпа структуры данных - то работать, как с любой обычной DLL